# Cannot GET /cool on Heroku nodejs tutorial locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, get

Here are the dependencies of my package.json file where i've added "cool-ascii-faces. I then need to update my index.js file to GET the /cool page so that on each reload I would see an ascii face. I'm getting a 404 error and it says 'Cannot GET /cool'

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "2.3.3",
    "express": "4.13.3", 
    "cool-ascii-faces": "~1.3"

  }
```

Below is my index.js file that calls declares cool

```
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/cool', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index')
});

app.get('/cool', function(request, response) {
  response.send(cool());
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
```

I then run npm install to update the dependencies and then heroku local, but get the 404 error.

Any help in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an exception when you start the node web server, due to a module dependency error.

Check your command/terminal window.  If you see a red warning message pointing to your module.js file, you have an exception:

```
$ heroku local
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | module.js:341
```

In this case, **you need to install the cool-ascii-faces module**.  In your 'node-js-getting-started' directory, use the following npm command to install:
`$ npm i -S cool-ascii-faces`

Also... you'll want to convert your index page route back to `'/'`.  Your routes logic should look like this:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
   response.render('pages/index')
});

app.get('/cool', function(request, response) {
   response.send(cool());
});
```

Otherwise, you'll always get the default 'pages/index' page when you hit the '/cool' route instead of a smiley face.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to include

```
 app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
 app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
     console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
 }
```

Heroku will run "npm start" to start your server and dynamically choose the port. You don't have to specify port explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

this problem happened for me. After I typed "git push heroku master", I typed "heroku open" and it worked.